# Hadoop and Amazon Web Services

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services

I want to self-learn Hadoop and Amazon Web Services online. Are there any good university courses or tutorials on the web? I could find books on Amazon on Hadoop or AWS but I want something hands on to try out and learn.

P.S. I went through the Yahoo Hadoop tutorial which was very useful.

Answer (score 8):

For hadoop, there is an awesome talk on Hadoop's ecosystem on AWS and EMR by the AWS team : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrRUAvKVfxw

Then there are a series of videos tutorial they have on EMR training:

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlKndm22bXw
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8YM2rAsAhY
3. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAZur5maWZE
4. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN0TPbj23dY
5. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lA93QzUny8
6. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSu8N2PoVbM
7. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06rz0h5-arw
8. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5D9dmZX9zo
9. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IUokcqDRcQ
10. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5i20nf3Kyzg
11. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4z6RxWAvqs

### **Update**: You can read this book as well : [Learning Big Data with Amazon Elastic MapReduce](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782173439)

The Cloudera team supports deployment to AWS, and provide a whole range of documentation. Try searching for Cloudera and AWS on google, and read the documentation [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html).

Answer (score 3):

I found the best way to pick up AWS from scratch was to follow the documentation and code samples provided by Amazon. There are also plenty of walk through videos provided on their YouTube channel, especially after the Amazon re:Invent conference. There are also some summits coming up soon. Most importantly, play around (within the free tier), make some mistakes, and have fun with it! Here are some links that should help:

[Training Information from Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/aws-training/)
[AWS Documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/)
[Sample Code and Libraries](http://aws.amazon.com/code/)
[AWS YouTube Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/AmazonWebServices)
[Upcoming AWS Summit Info](http://aws.amazon.com/aws-summit-2012/)

As for Hadoop, I am unfortunately out of the loop. I'll ask around and edit my answer if I find out a little more.

Comment: Great! Will explore them. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's an article from Cloudera that walks you through setting up [Hadoop on EC2](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/set-up-a-hadoophbase-cluster-on-ec2-in-about-an-hour/)

Cloudera is now keeping their [Hadoop on EC2 documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html) up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to comment in @Sixty4Bit 's answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Cloudera is keeping their tutorial up to the latest AWS configuration [HERE](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_on_EC2.html).