# Hadoop installation on Amazon cloud

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

i am new to Hadoop ,i likes to go in hadoop administration line so studied basics of hadoop and tried to install hadoop in pseudo distribution mode and installed successfully and run some basic examples also, now i need to improve me further,so i need to try a way to learn hadoop installation and configuration in real time so decided to go for Amazon micro instance ,can any one please tell how to install and configure hadoop in Amazon cloud.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075853/hadoop-and-amazon-web-services?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this personally and you will not really be able to use hadoop on a single micro instance due to memory restrictions.  IMHO you should atleast try a medium instance to run hadoop or better yet use their elastic-mapreduce api which is a modified version of hadoop. You can run a 3 node cluster for around 00.25 cents an hour. If you really want to learn big data this is the way I went.

You should check out their documentation here 
http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elasticmapreduce/